# Create RollBack task in Visual Basic Online for Release Management

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops, release-management, rmo

I want to create rollback task for Release Management in visual basic online.

i have some steps but it will take more time.

steps are:

1. Back Up: perform a backup of the original files to use for rollback later.
2. Deploy:Copy latest files from artifact to the target folder.

3.Configure — Make configuration changes to the setup.

4.Rollback — Rollback the files from backup in case Deploy failed. Delete backup before exiting.

we can see it will take long time while backup a database . So how we can optimize ?

is there any other method so we can implement and take less time when we will do rollback task ?

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t the built-in feature/task to rollback changes in release, you need to do it by your own script.

> There are various options that can be considered as a rollback
>   strategy.
>
> 1. Option#1 : Undo the change by redeploying the previous release
>
>    The first option is to simply redeploy the previously successful
>      release. This might work well for standalone applications.
>
>    Whenever an application depends on some external services or has a
>      database involved, this approach does not work well.  The dependent
>      services might have upgraded and no longer compatible with the
>      previous release.  The database might have changed the schema making
>      the previous release no longer healthy.
> 2. Option#2 : Fix the issue, do another release
>
>    The second option is to simply do nothing. Something went wrong,
>      troubleshoot it and fix it. Once we fix the issue, we can do another
>      release.
>
>    This however means the environment would remain unhealthy for some
>      time, as long as it takes for the fix to be ready and deployed.
> 3. Option#3 : Understand what failed in the deployment and make a temporary change for the time being
>
>    Both the above options are both valid approaches but with some
>      limitations.
>
>    That brings us to a third option. While the fix is getting ready
>      (option 2), make a minimum change to the environment to get it
>      temporarily healthy.

More information, please refer to: Implement [Rollback with Release Management for TFS 2015](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/03/28/implement-rollback-with-release-management-for-tfs-2015/) (Apply to VSTS)

Comment: the question was about optimising the roll back, not creating one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really optimise the backup/restore process.

If you use a Virtual Machene to deploy to then you should snapshot it prior to the upgrade, then a roll back is simply restoring the snapshot.

This will be much quicker, seconds, rather than minutes or hours...

Comment: how we can use VM , can you clarify it ?